# Azure Web App slots, why does Source default to production on a swap

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Every time I'm Swapping, the dropdown for 'source' is prefilled with 'production'.

Shouldn't the destination always be prefilled with 'production'

Since destination is the one that's supposed to stay live without interruption.  Source=Staging right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct that Staging should always be the source. And the good news is that despite what the UI says, Production is always treated as the Destination during the swap, regardless of the direction you specify. In other words, this is more or less a UI bug.

Additionally, note that if instead of clicking Swap while directly on the main site, you can first go into your Staging slot, and click swap from there. In that case, the default direction is what you expect. Though again, the direction the UI shows ends up being irrelevant during the swap (as long as Production is one of the two slots).

Comment: Thank you, that's a great explanation

Comment: So instead of one unexpected behaviour, we have two unexpected behaviours to counter that. Is it not an idea to just fix the UX problem? No one will know this, unnecessary annoying the Ambassadors for your platform.